# Angularjs ng-click and collapse getting errors

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

```
    <a ng-click="vm.getComment(post);isCollapsed{{post._id}} = !isCollapsed{{post._id}}">
```

1. I have written above code for display multiple collapsed on every
   click display that particular list and go belove error can any one tell me the above line is correct or not

   angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=32&p3=vm.getComment(post)%3BisCollapsed%7B%7Bpost._id%7D%7D%20%3D%20!isCollapsed%7B%7Bpost._id%7D%7D&p4=%7B%7Bpost._id%7D%7D%20%3D%20!isCollapsed%7B%7Bpost._id%7D%7D
       at http://localhost:6161/lib/angular/angular.min.js:6:412
       at s.throwError
       at kc.parse (http://localhost:6161/lib/angular/angular.min.js:276:122)
       at oa (http://localhost:6161/lib/angular/angular.min.js:71:38)
       at s (http://localhost:6161/lib/angular/angular.min.js:59:121)
       at s (http://localhost:6161/lib/angular/angular.min.js:59:253)

Comment: wrong syntax `isCollapsed{{post._id}}`, try `isCollapsed(post._id)`

Comment: what do you want to achieve from`isCollapsed{{post._id}}` .... is it complete string or  `isCollapsed` is a function

Comment: isCollapsed is not a function I used it as a variable for assigne Id like isCollapsed{{ID_place_here}} like this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't concatenate scoped variables as a string and expect to turn into a variable with that name. I suggest using an **object** or/and an array to store the information about the posts and simply toggle the booleans for each object. Here is a quick demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ids = [10, 21, 34, 100];
  $scope.isCollapsed = {
    "10": false,
    "21": false,
    "34": false,
    "100": false
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="id in ids">
    <button ng-click="isCollapsed[id] = !isCollapsed[id]">
      Hide {{id}}
    </button> <br>
    {{isCollapsed[id]}}
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```